# How to replace character from WordPress titles printed by plugin?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, plugins

I would like to replace special characters of my Wordpress's titles, to make linebreak + italic.

But, my issue is special because I am using the Wordpress plugin "[Posts per Cat](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/posts-per-cat/)" which is showing up my posts' titles per categories. So, I can't solve my issue by doing `str_replace` in conjunction with `get_title` function, because the plugin already gets the titles. How can I replace the character " | " by `<br>`, and `<i>` by italic in my titles, according to the HTML code below?

Is there a way I can do that in PHP, or CSS?

**Here is the HTML code : the titles are gotten in the `<a>` tag**

```html
<div id="ppc-box">

  <div class="ppc-box one">
    <div class="ppc">
      <h3>CURRENTLY</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/nouvelle-exposition-2/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article BOOK LAUNCH &amp; KÜNSTLERGESPRÄCH published at 18 juillet 2017 10 h 57 min">BOOK LAUNCH &amp; KÜNSTLERGESPRÄCH</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/alleinanspruch/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article PARKFIELD STUDIES | Marianna Christofides | &lt;i&gt;27 August – 30 August 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 18 juillet 2017 10 h 59 min">PARKFIELD STUDIES | Marianna Christofides | &lt;i&gt;27 August – 30 August 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/fourth-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article ALLEINANSPRUCH | Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber | &lt;i&gt;4 Februar – 30 April 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 52 min">ALLEINANSPRUCH | Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber | &lt;i&gt;4 Februar – 30 April 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="ppc-box one">
    <div class="ppc">
      <h3>PREVIEW</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/second-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article RESPAWN | Eloïse Bonneviot, Anne de Boer | &lt;i&gt;4 July – 30 July 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 50 min">RESPAWN | Eloïse Bonneviot, Anne de Boer | &lt;i&gt;4 July – 30 July 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/third-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article THE COMMON TOAD | Victoria Adam | &lt;i&gt;27 Mai – 30 Juli 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 51 min">THE COMMON TOAD | Victoria Adam | &lt;i&gt;27 Mai – 30 Juli 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unsure what you mean, could you clarify by explaining further?

Comment: @Script47 There are `<a>` tags in my HTML code. Into those `<a>` tags there is a `class="ppc-post-title"` and `title=" "`. In the `title=" "` there are my Wordpress's titles. I would like to add a function that replace the character "|" by linebreak and "<i>" by italic in those titles. I am looking for a way to achieve that, either in PHP or CSS.

Comment: @Script47 is it more clear? For example, if I write my title in wordpress admin like : "MY | TITLE", the " | " character would be replaced by a linebreak, and the title would get printed on two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve using some custom jQuery hack. Have a look.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('li a').each(function(){
    var title = $(this).text()
    title = title.replace("<i>","")
    title = title.replace("</i>","")
    title = title.replace(/\|/g,"")
    title = $(this).html(title)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ppc-box">

  <div class="ppc-box one">
    <div class="ppc">
      <h3>CURRENTLY</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/nouvelle-exposition-2/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article BOOK LAUNCH &amp; KÜNSTLERGESPRÄCH published at 18 juillet 2017 10 h 57 min">BOOK LAUNCH &amp; KÜNSTLERGESPRÄCH</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/alleinanspruch/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article PARKFIELD STUDIES | Marianna Christofides | &lt;i&gt;27 August – 30 August 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 18 juillet 2017 10 h 59 min">PARKFIELD STUDIES | Marianna Christofides | &lt;i&gt;27 August – 30 August 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/fourth-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article ALLEINANSPRUCH | Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber | &lt;i&gt;4 Februar – 30 April 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 52 min">ALLEINANSPRUCH | Arne Schmitt, Nico Joana Weber | &lt;i&gt;4 Februar – 30 April 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="ppc-box one">
    <div class="ppc">
      <h3>PREVIEW</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/second-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article RESPAWN | Eloïse Bonneviot, Anne de Boer | &lt;i&gt;4 July – 30 July 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 50 min">RESPAWN | Eloïse Bonneviot, Anne de Boer | &lt;i&gt;4 July – 30 July 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/third-post-test/" class="ppc-post-title" title="Article THE COMMON TOAD | Victoria Adam | &lt;i&gt;27 Mai – 30 Juli 2017&lt;/i&gt; published at 20 juillet 2017 17 h 51 min">THE COMMON TOAD | Victoria Adam | &lt;i&gt;27 Mai – 30 Juli 2017&lt;/i&gt;</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I gave you an idea, you can replace whatever you want using jQuery replace function. Let me know if you want any more assistance.
Thanks

Comment: thank you for your answer. Well, some more assistance would be appreciated! It doesn't seem to work. Here is the [link](http://temporarygallery.org/do-not-remove-this-folder/ausstellungen/) of the page where you can see the problem.

Comment: I am working on a .php file used as a template page for my wordpress. My jQuery link is placed in another .php file.

Comment: Hi, it's working as you can see by running the code. please try to put jQuery in footer.php inside script tag as same as shown in code above. you don't need to add anything else.

Comment: Ok, I can see I can replace character… but the linebreak and italic doesnt work… because if I add `<br>`, it replaces the " | " by "<br>" as a text, and not as a linebreak. Same for italic, how do I set up the italic? (jQuery is in my header.php file, is that ok?)

Comment: Ok, it is solved. It was because the jQuery was setted on `.text` and not `.html`. I have updated your answer. Thank you very much! :-)